# Trained HOG descriptor for upper body detection

Tags: opencv, svm, emgucv, object-detection

In my application I have to track the lecturer in a university lecture using a static camera. At the moment I'm using the default GPUHOGDescriptor from Emgu CV which works good if the whole body of the lecturer is visible. In the case where the lecturer is standing behind the desk, the detection works only around 20% of the time. My idea was to use a HOG detector which uses only the upper half of the body. I couldn't find any detector in the Internet but I'm sure that I'm not the first one with this problem. Or is there a fundamental problem that upper body detection does not work?

Can someone help me find one or share their descriptor? When I would want to train a HOG descriptor for myself, would it work to use a standard dataset like the INRIA and change only the size such that it takes only the upper half of the images?

Answer (score 1):

It would work by changing the size to 100*90 and by training the svm detector with a set of images of upper half portion . This would enhance accuracy but would cost you performance.
You need to get the HOG features from all of your positive and negative sample images using HOGDescriptor:compute functions, then feed the result to SVM library such as SVMlight. This page will help you to compute the feature and get the resulting model from SVM Light. The model will be available in genfiles/descriptorVector